# Pandoc conversion to PDF not providing colored hyptertext links

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

Consider the following snippet of a PDF generated from `pandoc` by way of `latex`.

[image]

Were you able to identify the hypertext links in there?  Neither was I...  It turns out that the *second* `Kaplan Meier` has a fully functional link to an external site.  But how do we divine that?

Note that the following option is already in place in the `pandoc` *preamble* - without which the hyperlink would not work at all:

```
link-citations: true
```

Short of a "real" solution I'll need to hack something to make hints for the links -  possibly via font manipulations.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you use a recent version of Pandoc (latest is v2.7.3), just add (for example) these to the commandline:

```
-V colorlinks=true \
-V linkcolor=blue \
-V urlcolor=red \
-V toccolor=gray
```

No need to fiddle with the `preamble`!

You can investigate the built-in LaTeX template shipping with your own Pandoc by this command:

```
pandoc -D latex | less
```

Then search for *link*, *url*, *color* etc. to see which variables are pre-defined there. Or:

```
pandoc -D latex | grep --color -E '(links|color|url|file)'
```

will give you an idea what other "links" you may want to manipulate.

Comment: Nice!  links were never happy being _red_ anyways (as in the defaults that can be seen in my answer below) .. well at least not until they were given a little attention/love . This is a nice complement to my answer - though I'll prefer adding to the preamble or to a `pandoc` template

Comment: As for the list of colors without scratching deeper under the surface, choose from [CSS/Properties/color/keywords - W3C Wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords). I find blue too striking and opt for teal instead.

Comment: this has lot of upvotes so I assume it works but it did not for me. I am converting from markdown. anyone else run into this?

Comment: @morpheus: You did not specify which specific steps of the answer you followed, and what were the exact results of these so I assume you did not follow them.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I added all the -V flags as the answer suggests. I did not do anything with the preamble as the answer suggests. SO I have a markdown file with no pandoc preamble. I run pandoc on it and use all the flags given. I use the xelatex pdf-engine. There is no error. A pdf is generated but the hyperlinks are not red or any other color for that matter. They just appear as normal text. They do work in the sense that I can click on them. lmk if anything else you need.

Comment: @morpheus: So you checked your Pandoc version? Which is it? You also checked the LaTeX template your Pandoc uses for "url|color|file|links" occurences?

Comment: this has to do with the version of pandoc I am using - 2.19. I asked in the mailing list and they helped me. Its a bug in that version fixed in next release.

Comment: dude, the version of pandoc i am using is more recent than the version mentioned in your answer (2.7.3). hard to believe how vain some people can be.

Comment: @morpheus: Sorry, I misread the version informaiton you gave as "2.1.9". My fault!

Comment: In case it helps - am on pandoc 3.1.11.1 on Windows, and this solution also did not work.   What did work, was adding `-f autolink_bare_uris`

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835461/pandoc-v-linkcolor-not-working-correctly-when-generating-pdf-with-latex

Answer (score 21):

You can also add to the meta-data `colorlinks: true`.

```
---
colorlinks: true
---

[Test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71426117/2657549)
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer on `tex` site that covers this: add the following to the `preamble` 
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319463/45938:

```
 - \hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
```

[image]

Now I see there were actually *two* links.