# Pandoc `-V linkcolor` not working correctly when generating PDF with LaTeX

Tags: latex, pandoc

I am using Pandoc 2.13.

If I run the following

```
pandoc -s foo.md                                        \ 
       -f markdown_phpextra+autolink_bare_uris+raw_tex  \
       --toc                                            \
       -V title="Pandoc Lunch and Learn"                \
       -V linkcolor:blue                                \
       -V mainfont="DejaVu Serif"                       \
       -V monofont="DejaVu Sans Mono"                   \
       -V geometry:letterpaper                          \
       -V geometry:margin=2cm                           \
       -V documentclass:article                         \
       -o foo.pdf
```

My links are blue, as expected.

However, if I try to use `-V linkcolor:red` or any other color for that matter the links still end up blue. If I use `V urlcolor=red` the link colors change as I'd expect. Why doesn't `linkcolor` work? Per the manual it seems like it should: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex

EDIT:
This is foo.md

```
# Foo

## Foo Bar Baz

[This link][1] will always be blue, even when I pass `-V linkcolor:red`

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835461/pandoc-v-linkcolor-not-working-correctly-when-generating-pdf-with-latex
```

Note that the link is blue when run with Pandoc 2.13 with this following command line args:

```
pandoc -s foo.md                                        \
       -f markdown_phpextra+autolink_bare_uris+raw_tex  \
       --toc                                            \
       -V title="Pandoc Lunch and Learn"                \
       -V linkcolor:red                                 \
       -V mainfont="DejaVu Serif"                       \
       -V monofont="DejaVu Sans Mono"                   \
       -V geometry:letterpaper                          \
       -V geometry:margin=2cm                           \
       -V documentclass:article                         \
       -o foo.pdf
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a [mre] so we can see which types of links you are trying to change?

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Note, if I explicitly specify `--pdf-engine=pdflatex` that doesn't change the behavior. Nor does using `--pdf-engine=xelatex`.

Comment: your markdown link is converted to `\href{...}{...}`. This is an external link for the hyperref package, thus `linkcolor`, which is used to set the colour of *internal* links, does not apply.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, and now I see it in the manual:

"linkcolor, filecolor, citecolor, urlcolor, toccolor
color for internal links, external links, citation links, linked URLs, and links in table of contents, respectively"

Could you please answer the question so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `linkcolor` of the `hyperref` package is to change the colour of *internal* links, e.g. if you link to another section in your document.

However your link gets converted to `\href{...}{...}` macro, thus the colour is to be specified via the `urlcolor` option.

For more information about these hyperref options, see section "3.5 Extension options" of the [user manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/hyperref/0)